# ng-class with condition and function in one ng-class directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want ng-class to have a condition and a function call. How do I make the changes necessary to:

```
<li ng-repeat="t in tabs" ng-class="{'active1':t.active,clickmenu(t.route)}" ng-click='clickMainMenu($index,t)'><div class='custom-menu-li' >{{t.heading | translate }}</div>       
</li>
```

so as to make `ng-class` have a condition and a function in one `ng-class` directive.

Comment: Can you be more clear in your question?

Comment: <li ng-repeat="t in tabs" ng-class="{'active1':t.active,clickmenu(t.route)}" ng-click='clickMainMenu($index,t)'><div class='custom-menu-li' >{{t.heading | translate }}</div>
       
      </li>     in the ng-class directive i want 2 condition and one should be function, when i use like this it throws some parse error

Comment: It's still not clear. Can you please explain what do you want and what have you tried in question body. There's a "code" button to mark the code so it won't be mangled.

Answer (score 0):

controller.js

```
$scope.isActive = function(t) {
    if (t.active) {
       clickmenu(t.route);
       return true;
    }
}
```

template.html

```
<li ng-repeat="t in tabs" 
    ng-class="{'active1': isActive(t)}" 
    ng-click='clickMainMenu($index,t)'>
  <div class='custom-menu-li' >{{t.heading | translate }}</div> 
</li>
```

NOTE: **This is not the ideal thing to do**. Your clickmenu will get called for every digest cycle.

Comment: i want to check on every condition

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this using `&&`:

```
<li ng-repeat="t in tabs" ng-class="{'active1':t.active && clickmenu(t.route)}" ng-click='clickMainMenu($index,t)'><div class='custom-menu-li' >{{t.heading | translate }}</div>       
</li>
```